# Text View Annotations

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I'm currently working on a project for iPhone which involves storing and displaying fair amounts of text in a secure manner. I'd like the user to be able to quickly and easily add annotations to this content, such as highlights of various colors, text color, and other rich text features (bold, italic, underline, etc.)

If at all possible, I'd like to have the ability to make notes to correspond to each annotation, if the user so desires.

I am currently using `NSAttributedString` in a `UITextView` (`attributedText` property) for this, but as I understand it (with what meager knowledge I have), attributes on `NSAttributedString` cannot be very well tapped to perform a method. While I could use the `UIMenuController`, that would require a user to reselect their entire annotation and manually undo or alter their original changes, and none of this brings me nearer to a system which would store text 'inline' along with the annotation...

I have heard of an `NSTextAttachment` or some such class, but it would seem that information on it's use is rather limited (or at least information I can coherently understand...)

My question, then, is this: Is there a way to accomplish this (at least the inline notes/highlights) with `UITextView`, or must I write up some HTML/CSS and use `UIWebView`? If so, where can I find some information on this that a simple man like myself can understand?

Thank you in advance, to whomever takes to time to comment or answer.